# Validate simple select query using Regular expression

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression pattern of below string (SQL query)?

```
Select col1,colo2,col3 form tablename where col1='this is a test'
```

It no needs to like order by distinct and etc.

 Just simple select and where clause.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This supports flexible spacing around your commas, etc..  The raw regex should look like this:

```
^Select\s+(?:\w+\s*(?:(?=from\b)|,\s*))+from\s+\w+\s+where\s+\w+\s*=\s*'[^']*'$
```

You'll need to escape any platform-specific characters (for example, in C#, `\s` needs to be `\\s`.)  In C#, it would look like this: `@"^Select\s+(?:\w+\s*(?:(?=from\b)|,\s*))+from\s+\w+\s+where\s+\w+\s*=\s*'[^']*'$"`

Also, don't forget to make your expression ignore case. In javascript it might end in `/i` like this: `/select ...+/i`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the regex flavour or tool you want to use for the check. But something like this could work:

```
/select ([a-z0-9_]+,?)+ from [a-z0-9_]+ where [a-z1-9_]+='[a-z0-9_ ]+'/
```

HTH