# Php Regex to find if string is mysql select statement

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to validate queries before executing them, If query is not a mysql select statement then i have to show message to user.

I found below regex from this link: 
[Validate simple select query using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473381/validate-simple-select-query-using-regular-expression)

```
$reg="/^Select\s+(?:\w+\s*(?:(?=from\b)|,\s*))+from\s+\w+\s+where\s+\w+\s*=\s*'[^']*'$/i";
```

next i wrote below code but it always prints not select query ($match is empty every time)

```
$string="select * from users where id=1";
preg_match_all($reg,$string,$match);
if(!empty($match)){
echo "select query";
//execute and process result
//$this->user_model->list($string);
}else{
   echo "not select query";
   //show_message('inv_query');
}
```

Please correct regex to validate sql select statement (select, from,where, join,orderby groupby all can be there in select statement).
 Or let me know other good way to do the task.

```
/*
some sample select statements
select * from users where id=1;

select * from users where id=1 AND name= 'Prabhu';

select * from users where id=1 AND name= 'Prabhu' order by name;

Select * from users where id=1 AND name= 'Prabhu' group by id order by name;

Select * from users join role on users.role_id=role.id where id=1 AND name= 'Prabhu' group by id order by name;
*/
```

Comment: post an example for the select query.

Comment: @AvinashRaj there are lots of permuattion & combination.

Comment: it would be better if you post all the possible Select statements http://regex101.com/r/bM7yR8/1

Comment: @Ravi How about this http://regex101.com/r/bM7yR8/3 ?

Comment: OMG Ravi... i can do that but regex101.com won't allow a very long pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not have something like:

```
$reg = "/^(\s*?)select\s*?.*?\s*?from([\s]|[^;]|(['"].*;.*['"]))*?;\s*?$/i";
```

works for the SQL select query examples: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6nP.

It also checks that the only SQL query being run is the select query, therefore it should only validate them. It does this by making sure that there is only one ; unless that ; is within a string, so the below will validate.

```
select * from users where id=1 AND name= 'Pra;bhu';
```

But this will not.

```
select * from users where id=1 AND name= 'Prabhu'; drop table;
```

And the regular expression which doesn't check for ; within a string and will fail if it is in it:

```
$reg = "/^(\s*?)select\s*?.*?\s*?from([\s]|[^;])*?;\s*?$/i"
```

Comment: Very nice, it is useful for admin-interfaces, to prevent drop or update

Comment: Very good, I'm using it for an Admin Dashboard for statistics to allow Admin in addition to multiple endpoints, can query database with sql directly. But a little correction for PHP, you need to escape the Double Quotes if you already use double quote for string : `$reg = "/^(\s*?)select\s*?.*?\s*?from([\s]|[^;]|(['\"].*;.*['\"]))*?;\s*?$/i";` . Can't edit because it's a less then 6 chars edit.

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful but it doesn't cover select statement which does not contain 'FROM' for example: `SELECT 22 as kind, 1 as code,'test' as title;`