# Using regular expressions for validating mysql statements

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I am writing a program in java. In a dialog a user need to input MySQL SELECT statement. Program must to validate the statement an continue to run. My question is: Is there a way and how to validate the statement with regular expressions. I need "only" regular expression pattern. Thanks.

Comment: Check [Php Regex to find if string is mysql select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092364/php-regex-to-find-if-string-is-mysql-select-statement) post. It will be a good start. However, I do not believe you can use regex to check every SELECT statement (at least with Java regex).

Comment: The syntax is very well [specified here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html). Converting it as a regular expression should be strightforward (albeit somewhat tedious). Where are you stuck?

Comment: Don't forget the lexical parts -- strings, escapes in strings, embedded commends, end-of-line comments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Well, maybe for extended regex, but for the original meaning of "regex" that stands for "Regular Expression", for "[Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)" - no.

Each SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z
```

However, since `y` itself can be a SELECT statement, this is at least as hard as the language of balanced parenthesis, which is irregular.

Answer (score 3):

If your objective is to allow only `SELECT` statements than grant only this operation to database user that opens the database connection. After that just handle the `SQLException`.

You really don't want to write and maintain validation code by hand because there are too many things to remember. For example if your JDBC connection is using `allowMultiQueries=true` parameter then one can execute multiple statements within String like `SELECT * FROM table; DROP TABLE table;`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is SELECT statement then it should start with SELECT. Below code is to match anything which starts with SELECT.

```
String sa = "THIS SELECT * from table;";
System.out.println(sa.matches("(?i)^select .*")); //FALSE as the input string is not valid select statement
sa = "SELECT * from table;";
System.out.println(sa.matches("(?i)^select .*")); //TRUE as the input string is  valid select statement
```

Comment: This is way too simplistic (and wrong). It even fails for `sa = "SELECT * form table;";` (note form instead of from)

Answer (score 2):

That's no place for a regex usage.

Elegant way to solve this is using **[BNF for Java](http://bnf-for-java.sourceforge.net/)** as validator of your select statements. If you will feed it SQL grammar, like this one [sql-99.bnf](http://www.savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf), you will have your statement validator in no time and for free.